# faiss ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement faiss (from versions: none)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, faiss

When Running Installation:

```
pip install faiss
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement faiss (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for faiss
```

also when i use conda:

```
conda install faiss
```

I get this error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - faiss
```

Comment: Please include what your OS and python version is

Comment: window 10 pro 64

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Faiss on Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/faiss/) is only a collection of pre-built binaries for MacOS and Linux and only for these python versions:

```
Python :: 2.7
Python :: 3.5
Python :: 3.6
Python :: 3.7
```

Your setup does not seem to match these specifications

[For conda](https://anaconda.org/search?q=faiss+), it does not exist in the std channels, but can be installed (for Linux and MacOS only) with:

```
conda install -c pytorch faiss-cpu
```

or

```
conda install -c pytorch faiss-gpu
```

Comment: it is only for linux and macOs ?

Comment: Officially it cannot be compiled on windows, see the projects [on the github page](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss). You could try to compile some [unofficial ports](https://github.com/bitsun/faiss-windows), but there is no guarantee that they would work and might also use an outdated version of the library

Answer (score 39):

Just to state the obvious, but for pip you can use gpu or cpu specifc builds:

```
pip install faiss-cpu
```

or

```
pip install faiss-gpu
```

Comment: how is this obvious lol

Comment: Since it was first answered that conda had separate cpu & gpu packages, looking for the same solution for pip was logical

Answer (score 3):

You can install faiss on Windows. Go to the conda prompt and type:

```
conda install -c conda-forge faiss-cpu
```

Answer (score 1):

## CPU-only version

$ conda install -c pytorch faiss-cpu=1.7.4 mkl=2021 blas=1.0=mkl

## GPU(+CPU) version

$ conda install -c pytorch -c nvidia faiss-gpu=1.7.4 mkl=2021 blas=1.0=mkl